# How to set expiration time to session in the controller?

Tags: session, symfony, session-timeout

I need to set a session with expiration time of 5min in controller. How do i do it? 
I need something like:

```
$this->container->get('session')->set('mysession', 'value', 'expiration');
```

in symfony2 way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is added [recently](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/b9de0be3499c938926401219711353476ed100c9). You can update to this commit or patch. From the code it seems you can set expiry time by following way,

```
$this->container->get('session')->getMetadataBag()->stampNew(300);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your session is already created, you can achive your goal with:

```
$this->container->get('session')->migrate($destroy = false, $lifetime = null);
```

`$destroy`: Whether to delete the old session or leave it to garbage collection.

`$lifetime`: Sets the cookie lifetime for the session cookie. A null value will leave the system settings unchanged, 0 sets the cookie to expire with browser session. Time is in seconds, and is not a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

To control the time of the active session (and idle time too) you have to do it in the controller this way (extract from: [session configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-lifetime) in the official doc):

```
$session->start();
if (time() - $session->getMetadataBag()->getCreated() > $maxTime) {
  $session->invalidate();
  throw new SessionExpired(); // redirect to expired session page
}
```

When time reaches your $maxTime session is "closed". You can put this code in the backend of your app as a function to call from the different methods to control the time.